# Spark Streaming StreamingContext dependency issue

Tags: scala, spark-streaming

I'm trying to use Spark Streaming with Scala but I'm getting errors and I can't figure out why.
The StreamingContext is the line giving the errors:

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("App_StreamingConsumer")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2))
```

These are the 2 errors:

> bad symbolic reference. A signature in StreamingContext.class refers
>   to term conf in package org.apache.hadoop which is not available. It
>   may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version
>   on the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when
>   compiling StreamingContext.class.

And:

> missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file
>   'StreamingContext.class'. Could not access term conf in package
>   org.apache.hadoop, because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check
>   your build definition for missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run
>   with -Ylog-classpath to see the problematic classpath.) A full rebuild
>   may help if 'StreamingContext.class' was compiled against an
>   incompatible version of org.apache.hadoop.

This question has been asked before:
[Spark Streaming StreamingContext error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26512432/spark-streaming-streamingcontext-error) the errors seem to be coming from a dependency issue but as far as I can tell my dependencies are all in order.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to include hadoop-core in my dependencies, I had hadoop-client and didn't realise I also needed core.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar problem, the reason is due to in the [build path] missing [hadoop] dependency. 
Here's my solution:
In the build.sbt file, add: "org.apache.hadoop"% "hadoop-hdfs"% "2.6.0" and run the command: [sbt eclipse], which will automatically add the [hadoop] dependency package to the project In the [build path].

Note:Be sure to use the [sbt eclipse] command,not [sbt update]